# what unit is bmi stored as in health kit HKUnit?

Tags: healthkit

What unit is BMI saved as in health kit?

```
self.bodyMassIndex = sample.quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.???)
```

Comment: you need HKUnit.count()